# SQL query - tagging system, delimited string + unique values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working for a client that stores item tags in the MySQL DB like so (I know, I know - not ideal):

```
coats_and_jackets-Woven_Jacket-brand:Hobbs;
coats_and_jackets-Woven_Jacket-color:Black;
coats_and_jackets-Woven_Jacket-style:Boucle;
coats_and_jackets-Woven_Jacket-pattern:Plain;
dresses-Pinafore-brand:COS;
dresses-Pinafore-color:Blue _ Navy;
dresses-Pinafore-style:Wool;
dresses-Pinafore-pattern:Plain;
shoes-Ankle_Boot-brand:Topshop;
shoes-Ankle_Boot-color:Black;
shoes-Ankle_Boot-style:Leather;
shoes-Ankle_Boot-pattern:Plain;
bags-Tote-brand:Mulberry;
bags-Tote-color:Brown _ Tan;
bags-Tote-style:Leather;
bags-Tote-pattern:Plain;
shoes-Ballet_shoes-brand:Chanel;
shoes-Ballet_shoes-color:Black;
shoes-Ballet_shoes-style:Leather;
shoes-Ballet_shoes-pattern:Plain;
accessories-Scarf-brand:Zara;
accessories-Scarf-color:Brown _ Tan;
accessories-Scarf-style:Wool;
accessories-Scarf-pattern:Checked;
```

Each tag is broken down into 4 parts like so: category-type-brand, category-type-color, category-type-style, category-type-pattern

Not all 4 parts of a tag are required and can be omitted from the DB.

I have been tasked with finding out how many tags an item has, so in this example 6 tags have been used, each with all 4 parts.

The query I have so far counts all the tag parts, in this example 24, but I cannot assume that each tag will have all 4 parts stored. So cannot divide the parts amount by 4 to get the amount of tags.

In this example, the 6 tags used are as follows:

Coats & Jackets (Woven Jacket) 
Dresses (Pinafore)
Shoes (Ankle boot)
Bags (Tote)
Shoes (Ballet Shoes)
Accessories (Scarf)

Now I'm not concerned about the category, type or parts (brand, color, style, pattern) - I'm just concerned about fetching the total amount of tags for this item.

Also, the data example above would be stored in a db row that looks like:

```
+----------+-------------+----------------------------+
|  ID      | meta_key    |   meta_value               |
+----------+-------------+----------------------------+
|        1 |   tags      |  coats_and_jackets-wove... |
+----------+-------------+----------------------------+
|        2 |   item_desc |  Fashion editor            |
+----------+-------------+----------------------------+
```

Help structuring this query would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The tags use hyphen as a separator.  Here is a method for finding the number of tags used by a given item:

```
select it.*, length(it.tags) - length(replace(it.tags, '-', ''))+1
from itemtags it
```

This replaces the hyphen with an empty string, and measures the difference in lengths.

Comment: thanks for your input, the hyphen is used to delimit the tag sub-sections i.e category-type-brand not the tags themselves. I've updated the description in the hope of providing more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your requirement correctly, how about something like this (with CTE used to demonstrate assumed table structure)

```
WITH CTE1(tag) AS(
    select 'coats_and_jackets-Woven_Jacket-brand:Hobbs' union
    -- ...
    select 'accessories-Scarf-color:Brown _ Tan' union
    select 'accessories-Scarf-style:Wool' union
    select 'accessories-Scarf-pattern:Checked'
)
, CTE2(tag_prefix) AS(
    select LEFT(tag, CHARINDEX('-', tag, CHARINDEX('-', tag) + 1) - 1) from CTE1
)
select tag_prefix, COUNT(*) from CTE2 group by tag_prefix
```

This will give you results of...

```
accessories-Scarf   4
bags-Tote   4
coats_and_jackets-Woven_Jacket  4
dresses-Pinafore    4
shoes-Ankle_Boot    4
shoes-Ballet_shoes  4
```

... which gives you the tag prefix and number of parts used.  From there you can count the individual rows or sum the number of parts or whatever else you need...

Comment: Thanks, but my poor description didn't give enough info it seems. I've updated in the hope it will make my problem clearer

Answer (score 0):

I've just realised that my solution is completely pointless given that I missed the 'mysql' tag ;) but I'll post it up here anyway.  Hopefully it can give you a pointer on how to proceed.

```
WITH CTE1(ID, meta_key, meta_value) AS(
    select 1, 'tags', 'coats_and_jackets-Wo...' union all
    select 2, 'item_desc', 'Fashion editor'
)
, TagsCTE AS(
    select t.ID, x.Item as tag_and_value
    from CTE1 t
    cross apply dbo.fn_SplitString(t.meta_value, ';') x
    where meta_key = 'tags' and LEN(x.Item) > 0
)
select ID, COUNT(parts_count) from (
    select ID, COUNT(*) as parts_count
    from TagsCTE
    group by ID, LEFT(tag_and_value, CHARINDEX('-', tag_and_value, CHARINDEX('-', tag_and_value) + 1) - 1)
) a group by ID
```

This gives results of:

```
1   6
```

Good luck.